# Boot ubuntu in my macbook pro

Tags: boot, macbook

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed in my macbook pro. It was working normally for a week. Then I got this problem saying 'efi is not ready yet'.
I tried to run boot-repair, but it does not help.
Here is the pastebin link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11696373/

Please help me!!